# Is there a way to find which version a Minecraft world was created in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have quite a bit of old minecraft worlds lying around. With the new launcher, I understand I can create profiles for older versions of minecraft, give them their own folders, and copy the saves over to these.

I don't want to load a save with a newer version than it was made. That usually gives ugly boundaries in world gen, or flips doors, or break things in other ways. I understand loading a newer world with an older version is even more likely to break things.

I do of course make backups, but I don't want to try every version of Minecraft for every save that I have. Is there a quick way I can find out which version of Minecraft a world was originally created in and/or last saved in?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can find it based on the `"DataVersion"` stored in the stats or advancements JSON files. Check the wiki's [data version](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_version) page to see which **client version** the data version corresponds to.

The easiest way I found to do it is by searching the advancements file for the world, for example:

```
$ cd ~/.minecraft/saves/"New World"
$ grep DataVersion advancements/*.json
  "DataVersion": 1976
```

If you have [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) installed, you can use it to get the number directly:

```
$ jq .DataVersion advancements/*.json
1976
```

Data version **1976** corresponds with client version **Java Edition 1.14.4**.

Answer (score 5):

As of now, underneath the world's name, original name, an last time played, it tells you the base gamemode, if there are cheats or not, and the version.

Comment: Note that this only works in 1.9+. If your world is under, it will display `unknown`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by *Cin316*

this is not possible as nothing about the MC version is saved in the file.

However an alternative moving forward is to put the version in your save name. so "My world 1.7.2" by doing this you will be creating your own metadata as it were so you can keep track of your saves.

I understand this doesn't help with already created worlds unless you know the version but it will help you with anything you create from now

Comment: +1 for advising better naming conventions!

Comment: This question is old, but there's a way now, the Minecraft client says the version. I don't know how though, looking for it RN.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but you can use the last date the file was modified, and check it with the update history.

Comment: This will get you close, but what about the people that don't update right away?

Answer (score 1):

In the game, use this command:

```
/data get entity @s DataVersion
```

This will show a number that indicates the data version.

You can see which client version is associated with that data version by checking the wiki here:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_version#List_of_data_versions

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the game does not record which version of Minecraft a world was created in.  Neither Minecraft nor any third party utilities will be able to find this information.  Sorry to bring bad news.  :(

Comment: then how does it know how to update the save in newer versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux (or using Cygwin on Windows), I've made [set of tools](https://gitlab.com/jjustra/minecraft-worlds-toolbox/-/tree/main) to solve this.

Comment: When you just post a link without any explanation of what you did, why, or how, it makes a post look like spam. I can tell that you put effort into making the tools you did, but I don't think creating a set of tools like this is an expected response to this question. Therefore, if you don't want to look like a spammer, I would suggest justifying why and how you made these tools, and what they do. You can certainly improve this answer, try [edit]ing it.